# Dealing with ArrayOfXsdAnyType

Tags: java, jsp, soap, soapui

My wsdl file element looks like this

```
<element name="getHemodialysisHospitalResponse">
<complexType
><sequence><element name="getHemodialysisHospitalReturn" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType"/></sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
```

when I try to get the data in Soap UI I’m getting the response

Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://serviceimpl.com.echannelling">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getHemodialysisHospital/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getHemodialysisHospitalResponse xmlns="http://serviceimpl.com.echannelling">
         <getHemodialysisHospitalReturn>
            <getHemodialysisHospitalReturn xsi:type="ns1:Hospital" xmlns:ns1="http://serviceimpl.com.echannelling">
               <ns1:hosId xsi:type="xsd:string">H56</ns1:hosId>
               <ns1:hosName xsi:type="xsd:string">The Singapore Clinic</ns1:hosName>
            </getHemodialysisHospitalReturn>
         </getHemodialysisHospitalReturn>
      </getHemodialysisHospitalResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I’m not able to get the same return value in code using java
how to get this value "The Singapore Clinic" in code. Generated method returns a data type ArrayOfXsdAnyType but it is returning an empty set in the code

Comment: Can you share you're java client where you don't get a result?

Comment: EchannellingWebServiceImplService ews=new EchannellingWebServiceImplService();
  EchannellingWebServiceImpl ewsi=ews.getEchannellingWebServiceImpl();
  out.println(ewsi.getHemodialysisHospital().getItem().get(0).toString());
    out.print(ewsi.getHemodialysisSpec().getItem().get(0).getValue());

I have created an Object in the jsp page and tried to acces the details. I'm getting correct output for
out.print(ewsi.getHemodialysisSpec().getItem().get(0).getValue());
but getting an empty set for
out.println(ewsi.getHemodialysisHospital().getItem().get(0).toString());
but it should not be empty set